# Why is my VM instance stuck when I try to do SSH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I build a VM default settings with Ubuntu 16 and CentOS 7 (those are the ones I've tried) I keep getting stuck when I try to do SSH. The message is:

```
Establishing connection to SSH server...
```

And then it times out with:

```
You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error.
Wait a few moments and then try again. (#79)
```

I enabled OS login hoping the behavior will change but it just stays stuck.

Everything is default except that I enabled "HTTP and HTTPS" access when creating the VM. (I tried building it without these options checked and I get to the same problem.

Comment: Check out some docs for troubleshooting this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/890374/unable-to-ssh-onto-gce-vm-after-reboot/890444#890444) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh). Also note that you cannot use both metadata-based SSH keys and OS Login to connect to an instance.

Comment: Are you SSHing from the Cloud Console or from a command line/tool?

Comment: Seems we need more information here, 
how were those instances created?
Command line (gcloud)?
in Cloud Shell?
Are you using the Cloud SDK in you desktop/ laptop?
did you correctly configured the user ?
Where are you seeing this error message?
What tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 2):

Can you make sure that you have port 22 allowed from your network to the VM?
You can create a rule by going to VPC --> Firewall Rules --> Create New Rule.

This [page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) has detailed steps.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As manesioz commented, follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) guide to discard the common issues, as you said that this happens immediately after creation, most likely you're missing some firewall rules. Also consider to do a nmap scan to see if the port 22 is open in your instance. Do the next in cloud shell:

> sudo apt-get install -y nmap
>
> nmap -Pn YOUR_EXTERNAL_IP

Look for port 22 open